# How do I serve all types of images?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write some code in node.js that uses the extension name of a url to find images. For example if the extension name of the url is .jpg , it will find and respond with the .jpg file. If the url extension name is .png or .svg it will serve the appropriate file with the correct file type.

This is what I have:

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {


if(path.extname(req.url) == ".png" || path.extname(req.url) == ".gif" || path.extname(req.url) ==    ".svg") {

fs.readFile(path.basename(req.url), function(err, data) {

        var extname = path.extname(req.url);

        switch(extname) {

        case ".png":
            var ext = "image/png";
        case ".svg":
            var ext = "image/svg+xml";
        case ".gif":
            var ext = "image/gif";

            }

    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':ext});
    res.end(data);
    console.log(ext);

});

}



}); 

server.listen(80);
```

This is driving me nuts because when I observe the headers, its not using the correct content-type. I used a switch statement to put the correct content type into a variable based on the extension name. So if the extension name is .png , it would put "image/png" into a variable called **ext**. I put the variable ext in the writeHead section right after 'content-type': ...

I am console logging the variable "**ext**" and I am getting "image/gif" no matter what. Even if the extname is .svg or .png.

At this moment if I look for a file on my server domain.com/picture.svg and check the headers, it will show : content-type:image/gif ..My switch statement clearly says if the path.extname(req.url) is ".svg", then "image/svg+xml" should be put in the variable **ext**.

I tried weird things like put quotes around the variable "ext" and it actually displays the .svg file that I requested. Even though the headers look like this: content-type:ext.

I am very confused and I need some help.

**What is wrong with my code?**
**How do I display .jpg .png .svg .gif using only a block of a code in node.js?**

NO EXPRESS OR FRAMEWORKS! I am looking for a pure node.js solution.

Comment: @zvona - That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @zvona, make your comment an answer.

Comment: Everything works now thanks. I have a question though. I am console logging extnames , basenames , and the variable produced by the switch statement. .gif and .png console log with no problem, but .svg never console logs anything. Even in the headers I see the content-type:ext. Ext is the variable. But gif and png display correctly: content-type:image/gif and content-type:image/png. I have added the breaks in the switch statement too. Does .svg act differently somehow?

Comment: Never mind about my above comment. I use cloudflare which caches images, that is why I was not seeing the requests!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code it seems you're missing "break" on each case and that's why it evaluates all the way to the last case? Read the reasons behind this at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

> Example: What happens if I forgot a break?
>
> If you forget a break then script will run from the case where
>   criteria is met, and will run the case after that regardless if
>   criteria was met.

Your code should look (more) like:

```
var extname = path.extname(req.url);
var allowed = [".png", ".gif", ".svg"];
var ext = "";

if (!!~allowed.indexOf(extname)) {
    fs.readFile(path.basename(req.url), function(err, data) {
        switch(extname) {
            case ".png":
                ext = "image/png";
                break;
            case ".svg":
                ext = "image/svg+xml";
                break;
            case ".gif":
                ext = "image/gif";
                break;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':ext});
        res.end(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why does .png and .gif get === , and .svg only get == ?

Comment: It's called a typo. Will fix :) (and re-factor some more)

Comment: What does !!~ do at the beginning of the if statement?

Comment: The problem is that .index() function returns -1 when extname is not found. However -1 is interpreted as "true". ~(-1) will return 0 and !!(0) is just converting it to boolean value "false". So, part "!!" is not mandatory - it's just to indicate that we want to handle this value with some other original data type as a boolean.